# <p> tag breaks out of its <div>

Tags: html, css

When resizing the `<p>` tag breaks out of its parent `<div>`, how can I make it responsive and stay in the `<div>` HTML code thats what I achieved with HTML and CSS:

```html
<div class="text3">
  <div class="firstext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="secondtext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui.
    </p> 
  </div>
  <img class="logo" src="/images/logo.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Here is the css code:

```css
.text3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
}
.firstext {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
.firstext p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 50vh;
    height: auto;
}
.secondtext {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
.secondtext p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    top: 20%;
}
```

Comment: don't use position:absolute

Comment: This is one of the fundamentals of CSS you haven't learned yet and I suggest you read up on positioning in CSS.

Comment: thanks i will look into it

Answer (score 0):

**the problem is in absolute**

In `position: relative`, the element is positioned relative to itself. However, an absolute positioned element is relative to its parent.

An element with `position: absolute` is removed from the normal document flow. It is positioned automatically to the starting point (top-left corner) of its parent element. If it doesn’t have any parent elements, then the initial document  will be its parent.

Since position: absolute removes the element from the document flow, other elements are affected and behave as the element is removed completely from the webpage.

**check for more information**
[How to use the position property in CSS to align elements](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26)

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Temani Afif, absolute should realistically only be kept to your parent div, in this case .text3

in the following codepen I have modified your CSS and I believe I have achieved the outcome you are looking for: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJYYQw)

```
 .text3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
position: absolute;
}
.firstext {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
.firstext p {
    position: relative;
    left: 35%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 50vh;
    height: auto;
}
.secondtext {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
.secondtext p {
    position: relative;
    left: 35%;
    top: 20%;
}
```

if this isn't what you were looking for, you could also achieve similar results with flexbox.

```
 .text3 {
  display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

and removing the display styling from the other elements